# intermittent problem with automatic file upload

Tags: file, delphi, upload

I have written some code in Delphi/Pascal to upload a file to a website.  To accomplish it, I run the code below in a thread immediately before I click the upload button.  The thread looks for the windows upload file dialog and fills it in.

It works most of the time.  Occasionally but with some frequency, it does not work.  What is happening is that I am entering the full filename with path into the upload dialog.  For some reason, sometimes windows will remove the path from the filename.  Since the given filename (without the path) does not exist in the directory that windows is currently in, the upload fails.

For example, I am uploading "c:\uploads10\123.pdf", Windows will (sometimes) truncate the filename to "123.pdf" which does not exist in whatever directory the upload dialog defaults to, so the upload fails.

This has been driving me crazy for a while.  Can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
  for Looper := 1 to 2 do
  begin
    UploadDialogHandle := FindWindow('#32770', 'Choose File to Upload');
    if UploadDialogHandle = 0 then
      Sleep(100)
    else
    begin
      SetFileUploadDialogPosition(UploadDialogHandle);
      break;
    end;
  end;
  if UploadDialogHandle = 0 then
    exit;

  for Looper := 1 to 1 do
  begin
    // Find the child ComboBoxEx32 window
    UploadDialogFileEditHandle := FindWindowEx(FileUploadDialogHandle, 0,
      'ComboBoxEx32', '');
    if UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0 then
      Sleep(100)
    else
      break;
  end;

  if UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0 then
    exit;

  for Looper := 1 to 1 do
  begin
    // Find the child ComboBox window
    UploadDialogFileEditHandle := FindWindowEx(UploadDialogFileEditHandle, 0,
      'ComboBox', '');
    if UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0 then
      Sleep(100)
    else
      break;
  end;
  for Looper := 1 to 1 do
  begin
    // Find the child Edit window
    UploadDialogFileEditHandle := FindWindowEx(UploadDialogFileEditHandle, 0,
      'Edit', '');
    if UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0 then
      Sleep(100)
    else
      break;
  end;

  if UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0 then
    exit;

  Result := False;
  if (UploadDialogHandle = 0) or (UploadDialogFileEditHandle = 0) or
    (FileUploadButtonHandle = 0) then
    exit;
  StrPCopy(aUploadFileName, FileNameString);
  SendMessage(UploadDialogFileEditHandle, WM_SETTEXT, SizeOf(aUploadFileName),
    Integer(@aUploadFileName));
  Sleep(200);
  SendMessage(UploadDialogFileEditHandle, WM_GETTEXT, SizeOf(FileEditContents),
    Integer(@FileEditContents));

  if (StrComp(aUploadFileName, FileEditContents) = 0) then
    SendMessage(FileUploadButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Your last 2 calls to `FindWindowEx()` are wrong, and unnecessary. Once you have a `ComboBoxEx`'s `HWND`, you can send it `CBEM_GETCOMBOCONTROL` and `CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL` messages to get its child `ComboBox` and `Edit` `HWND`s. On the other hand, why are you manipulating a File Open Dialog in this manner to begin with? Depending on which version of the dialog is being used, you might be able to send the dialog a `CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT` message instead. But really, why are you manipulating another app to upload a file for you, instead of, you know, actually uploading the file *yourself*?

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I am actually doing this manipulation in my own program.  My program has an embedded webbrowser.  Besides uploading the file, it is filing-in a lot of other information needed with the upload.  All of the required inputs are contained in a database so this saves my users a lot of time.

Comment: "*I am actually doing this manipulation in my own program*" - then you are absolutely going about this the wrong way. "*My program has an embedded webbrowser*" - why are you using an embedded WebBrowser instead of an HTTP client component/library? Such as Indy's `TIdHTTP`, or Embarcadero's `TRESTClient`. They would make this job a lot easier and more straight-forward. And you would then be able to use your own `TOpenDialog` or `TFileOpenDialog`, if needed.

Comment: I have not ever played with those component libraries.  The way my program works, is that I log in to the website that is controlled by a third party.  My program automates much of the website's interactions but the end user can always make manual entries if necessary.  Sometimes the third party makes changes to their website that will break my code and I have to make changes.  In this type of situation, will those component libraries work better?  Second question, I am trying to use your earlier suggestions.  My compiler does not recognize CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL.  What unit do I need to add?